# Changing Cell AccessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessoryview

I have a table view with one row that switches between two accessory views.  The problem is that when I have it show the non-default accessory view, I can't get it to switch back.

Here is how I'm trying to do it.  If the actionAlertBadge is hidden the accessory view for row at index 1 should be accessory, which it is.  If actionAlertBadge is not hidden, the accessory view for row at index 1 is actionAlertBadge.  If the accessory is actionAlertBadge, it should change to being accessory if row at index 1 is selected, but it doesn't.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (!(indexPath.row == 1))
    {
        cell.accessoryView = accessory;
    }

    badgeNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]];

    actionAlertBadge = [JSCustomBadge customBadgeWithString:badgeNumber];
    actionAlertBadge.frame = CGRectMake(83, 6, 30, 30);

    if ([badgeNumber isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        actionAlertBadge.hidden = YES;
    }

    if (actionAlertBadge.hidden == NO)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cell.accessoryView = actionAlertBadge;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cell.accessoryView = accessory;
        }
    }
```

And in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        ActionAlertsIpad *actionAlerts = [[ActionAlertsIpad alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        WebViewControllerIpad *wvc = [[WebViewControllerIpad alloc]init];
        [actionAlerts setWebViewController:wvc];
        actionAlerts.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];
        actionAlertBadge.hidden = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:actionAlerts animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding `[tableView reloadData];` in the row selection code.